# How do I process files on GCP through SFTP and Stateful Sets

Tags: storage, google-cloud-platform, sftp, kubernetes

I'm looking for a little direction here and am having some troubles. I have an application that needs to process some simple csv files and I'm struggling to connect the appropriate technologies.

1. I have an application deployable as a container. I believe that I should deploy it as a stateful set as it requires access to a persistent file system.
2. I believe I need a Persistent Volume Claim on which to mount my stateful set
3. Where I run into a little confusion is how the files get into that volume. I need a SFTP server so that 3rd parties can drop files into a location for the application to pick up and process.

I'm not quite sure the best method of connecting this together. Can I have a Compute VM also mount the same location as the Persistent Volume Claim?

It seems like a straightforward task, but the proper design here eludes me. Help is appreciated.

**Running Google GCP/Kubernetes**

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) which is simpler than StatefulSet and can also use [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/). Read the docs carefully, as the 'StatefulSet' is a bit of a misnomer.

You want a sshd server container (which accepts sftp clients' connections) to have access to the same volume as the application container, put both containers in the same Pod and mount the same single volume in both containers. There is an [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/).

There are few ideas on how can you achieve that on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/gf4705/gcp_sftp_for_google_buckets/).